# Takbeer and Rafa Yadain

Tags: practical-islam, sunnah

What is Takbeer and Rafa Yadain? Why we raise our hands till our ears to say Allahu Akbar. What this gesture symbolizes?

Comment: This question title suggests that rafa' al-yadain is a synonym of takbeer which is clearly misleading as except within prayer there's no connection between both. Further takbeer is a kind of dhikr and rafa' al-yadain is an act. Please learn your own religion before teaching others.

Comment: A.O.A    
Brother if you read the answer carefully, I have explained Rafa yadain as an act or gesture and not as AllahuAkbar. Mistakenly in the title it is mentioned as "or" inspite of "and". However, both are necessary  in the completion of Rafa Yadain. Secondly, Dont become too harsh on others, because Islam always emphasis on constructive criticism. may be there is a proof reading mistake. Anyhow thanks for the correction.

Comment: I don't see any improvement here you still set an act equal to a dhikr! And Takbeer is not equal to rafa' al-Yadain. My understanding of constructive criticism is pointing at what is wrong and explaining why and I did so.

Comment: I think you have not read the whole answer. its not about Rafa Yadain is equal to Zikar. Its about the symbolical meaning of the gesture called Rafa Yadian. Anyhow. sometime, people make comment after reading the title only.

Comment: I've read your answer and question and still there's the issue that you don't really distinguish between rafa'a al-Yadayn as an act and saying Allahu akbar at the same time (which is a dhikr) or takbeer or as it is mostly known the takbeer at the beginning of the prayer act and dhikr which is also called takbirat al-Ihraam. And as long there's this ambiguity my position is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum,

The translation for the takbeer or takbir (AllahuAkbar) is Allah is the greatest. One form of takbeer is used when saying AllahuAkbar at the start of your salat. Another form of takbeer is said on eid day (AllahuAkbar, AllahuAkbar, La ilaha illalah, AllahuAkbar, AllahuAkbar, Wa lillah il Hamd)

Rafal yadain is something done in salat, before a person goes into ruku and after ruku. It’s an act of sunnah performed by Prophet Muhammed PBUH. Some fiqh’s deem it permissible whereas some do not, I cannot give information on this as I am not educated but I hope my answer has covered the question.

Answer (score -1):

Our namaz starts with a Sunnah called ***Rafa Yadain***, *(Takbeer)*.

Have you ever thought consciously about this gesture called **Rafa Yadain**? that why we raise our hands almost to the ears by saying ***Allahu Akbar***. (A confession about the magnification of Allah).

It can be understood through the example of a student in the class room, who raises his hand to show his presence or wants to answer or asks a question.

In the same way, **Rafa yadain** is a gesture towards ***Allah Subhan Tallah*** that I am standing empty handed in front of you with the confession that I am incapable of attaining anything without your help and support.  Now, I am fully attentive and ready for having conversation with you by putting all my love and soul into it.

Then we recite ***Allahu Akbar*** with the declaration of faith that we truly honored the greatness of ***Allah Subhan Tallah***.

The words ***Allahu Akbar*** are a celebration of life, the first words, whisper in our ears when we born, we read in Azan, Prayers, Eid festivals, halal slaughtering of animas, in times of distress, joy, gratitude, battle and protest etc.

Anyhow, some Arab people make will that their hands must be kept outside their shroud (kafan) in the position of **Rafah yadain** in order to show their children that they are going to meet their Lord empty handed, irrespective of their wealth and bank balance, they have in their life. And this is way they make their children to understand the real meaning of **Rafah yadain.**

Now the point to think is that have you ever feel in this way while saying your prayer?